# app updates not showing in the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

I have pushed a new version of my app.

On google developer console it is published and all old versions are unpublished but on Google Play Store it is still showing old version. I uploaded the app 2days before so it should have been updated and on developer console, it is showing as updated.

I already clear play store cached and data but still showing old app version don't know why.

I have checked, on all devices showing old versions. does anyone know why this is happening??

[image: Screen shot of update]

Comment: Check this one: https://www.androidpit.com/google-play-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had chat with google support and as per chat they have made some changes to the review process, so it may take more time to review the app thoroughly.
they also said that it usually takes a few hours and up to a few days, depends on different circumstances.
also, they provided the [link for refrence](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en)

I thought to post it as an answer as if this happens with someone so this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue. It takes some time to show your app new version on Play Store. They implement it on regional based. So don't worry it will be available in a few hours.

Comment: Kindly send the link of your application, let me check.